# How does solve ADF solution for Update Preview issue in XPM

Tags: ambient-data-framework, 2013-sp1

When I click on "update preview", "update preview" show again and again.

Because Real URL is different from URL of Broker DB, the above problem happen.

So, I solve the problem by using ADF.

I confirm that custom claimProsessor is work and the variables claim store have by the following question.

[About ADF solution for Update Preview issue in XPM](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/13604/about-adf-solution-for-update-preview-issue-in-xpm)

next To solve the XPM issue, I implement custom claimProsessor.

the solution is that Real URL is same to URL of Broker DB.

so I implement that the value of taf:request:full_url is changed to URL of Broker DB.

1. implement program and build

   ```
   public class AmbientDataFrameworkExtensionHandler extends AbstractClaimProcessor {

   @Override
   public void onRequestStart(ClaimStore claimStore) throws AmbientDataException {
       File file = new File("/tmp/log_adf1.txt");
       FileWriter filewriter = null;
       try {
           filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
           TreeMap<URI, Object> claims = new TreeMap<URI, Object>();
           Map<URI, Object> allClaims = claimStore.getAll();
           for (URI claimUri : allClaims.keySet()) {
               filewriter.write(claimUri.toString());
               filewriter.write("\n");
               filewriter.write(allClaims.get(claimUri).toString());
               filewriter.write("\n");
               if (claimStore.isReadOnly(claimUri)) {
                   if ("taf:request:full_url".equals(claimUri.toString())) {
                       claims.put(claimUri, allClaims.get(claimUri).toString().replace("/xxxx/", "/yyyy/"));
                   } else {
                       claims.put(claimUri, allClaims.get(claimUri));
                   }
                   filewriter.write("read only");
                   filewriter.write("\n");
               } else {
                   filewriter.write("not read only");
                   filewriter.write("\n");
               }
           }
           try {
               claimStore.clearReadOnly();
               for (URI claimsUri : claims.keySet()) {
                   claimStore.put(claimsUri, claims.get(claimsUri));
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               filewriter.write(e.getMessage());
           }
           filewriter.write("\n");
           filewriter.write("final");
           Map<URI, Object> allAfterClaims = claimStore.getAll();
           for (URI claimAfterUri : allAfterClaims.keySet()) {
               filewriter.write(claimAfterUri.toString());
               filewriter.write("\n");
               filewriter.write(allAfterClaims.get(claimAfterUri).toString());
               filewriter.write("\n");
           }
           filewriter.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AmbientDataException(e);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestEnd(ClaimStore claimStore) throws AmbientDataException {
       File file = new File("/tmp/log_adf2.txt");
       FileWriter filewriter = null;
       try {
           filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
           TreeMap<String, Object> claims = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
           Map<URI, Object> allClaims = claimStore.getAll();
           for (URI claimUri : allClaims.keySet()) {
               claims.put(claimUri.toString(), allClaims.get(claimUri));
               filewriter.write(claimUri.toString());
               filewriter.write("\n");
               filewriter.write(allClaims.get(claimUri).toString());
               filewriter.write("\n");
           }
           filewriter.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AmbientDataException(e);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onSessionStart(ClaimStore claimStore) throws AmbientDataException {
       File file = new File("/tmp/log_adf3.txt");
       FileWriter filewriter = null;
       try {
           filewriter = new FileWriter(file);
           filewriter.write("onSessionStart");
           filewriter.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AmbientDataException(e);
       }
   }
   ```

   }
2. create cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xml (configuration file)
3. configure cd_ambient_conf.xml
4. restart webservice
5. access the webpage
6. confirm the result

   I confirm that Real URL is same to URL of Broker DB.
   but XPM issue is not solved.
   Is My solved approach wrong or my implementation wrong ?

I refer to the follow pages. the follow pages are very useful for me.

http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-C6537469-7D70-4F82-B6C9-7883213F9F1B

http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.jp/2013/10/managing-claims-and-their-scope-in-sdl.html

http://erichuiza.blogspot.jp/2012/07/ambient-data-framework-in-nutshell.html

https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/blob/master/AmbientDataFramework/ClaimStore.jsp